# Where's my ASP.NET 4.0

Tags: iis-7, asp.net, .net, .net-4.0

I have installed .NET 4.0 to a Windows Server 2008.
I have run aspnet_regiis -i.

But with my new site on IIS7 I can't seem to select v4.0 as the framework.
I see 2 new app pools ASP.NET 4.0 and Classic 4.0
but surely all apps don't share the same v4.0 app pool right? What am I missing?

Comment: You may potentially also want this hotfix: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/958854. See also my question http://serverfault.com/questions/185623/edit-net-4-0-machine-key-settings-at-a-computer-wide-level-in-iis-7-0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the server x64?

In this case, you should run `aspnet_regiis.exe` from the `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319` folder, not from `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319`.

Answer (score 1):

To use .NET 4.0 you'll need to move your app to the Application pool.  Not all apps have to share the same app pool as it's simply a way to isolate apps so basically you can create app pools to your hearts desire.  What you can't do is put a .NET 3.5 app into a 4.0 pool however as the pool actually loads the .NET Framework version you configure it to into memory.